# Stop screen redirecting output without kill the screen

Tags: bash, unix, redirect, terminal, gnu-screen

I run a script in a screen terminal (`screen -L`), redirecting its output into a `screenlog.0` file.
Now the file is getting dangerously big and I was wondering if you knew a way in order to stop the output to be saved still preserving the script running. I can’t actually stop the script now.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the file descriptor for `screenlog.0` with one for `/dev/null`, which will just discard whatever is written to it.

GDB can do that. Use [this wrapper script](http://users.linpro.no/ingvar/fdswap.sh.txt) by Robert McKay to change file descriptor on the fly:

```
./fdswap.sh /path/to/screenlog.0 /dev/null $pid_of_process_writing_to_log
```

Disclaimer: I did not write that script. Although I already used it with success, I cannot guarantee that it will always work as expected.